# How to restore php.ini in CentOS

Tags: centos, php.ini

I have a problem in restoring my php.ini in the server. I was changing some line but I accidentally cut off and save.

Any idea how to restore it back?

Environment:

CentOS release 6.3 (Final) x86_64
PHP 5.3.17

Comment: if you haven't yet restarted apache (and are thus still using the pre-editing php.ini), you could save the info from a phpinfo page to help figure out what options you had.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob in this matter. Any way I can export data from phpinfo?

Comment: this can happen to anyone. it should not be closed IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Restore from a backup.

Sorry, there's no magic sysadmin way to recover a file you deleted/saved over/set on fire/etc.

Comment: Right but my bad that I dont have a backup. Is there any way I can get a default php.ini somewhere?

Comment: @ninjascorner, if you don't have a backup you not only don't get any sympathy, you're also on the wrong site. This site is for IT professionals and professionals make sure they backup before changing things.

Comment: @ninjascorner you could do an install on another machine to try to get a "default" `php.ini` ... not that this is a good idea, mind you, but it's possible.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it now and it works..thanks man...I'm just learning in Unix and this will be my first lesson. Thank you for helping me even if I'm not a professional. Mistake is a key to become a better one I guess.

Comment: Other locations exist for the default ini files:

    `/usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development`
    `/usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-production`
    `/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production`
    `/usr/share/php5/php.ini-development`
    `/etc/php.ini.default`

Comment: @JohnGardeniers: I just logged in not only to flag your comment as unkind and useless; I also wanted to tell you you're an a$$h0l3

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck as far as 'undeleting' it is concerned.

It's possible to restore one file from an RPM, see [here](http://www.linux-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/355-extract-1-file-from-rpm/) for an example.